# How do you scale a polygon patch in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the example below, I create a rectangular patch using matplotlib.patches.Polygon. Is there a way to scale the patch before adding it to the plot?

I've tried using matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D in a variety of ways with no success.  As usual, the matplotlib documentation on transformations is woefully insufficient.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot([-3,3],[-3,3])

x = [-1,0,1,1,0,-1]
y = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
poly = Polygon( zip(x,y), facecolor='red', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Scale it how? What have you actually tried so far (what were the variety of ways you tried), and what errors did you get (what constitutes success)? As usual, the problem description in this question is woefully insufficient (sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: I think thematplotlib documentation is pretty good. E.g. it has a complete [transforms tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). In case you are able to say what you don't like, they will probably be happy to hear about it at their [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Please point to the section of that tutorial that describes scaling polygons in place?  You're linking to a three page tutorial on a package that contains hundreds of methods. I wouldn't call that useful documentation.

Comment: @tom Please look up affine transformations in a dictionary.

Comment: I am pretty sure that @tom knows what affine transformations are. His comment was meant to ensure quality of questions here on SO. Please read [ask]. He is completely right in saying that "scale" is not well defined here. The comment below my answer confirms that: "scale" seems to be something beyond a simple factor, without this fact being mentionned in the question. Seeing the attitude of your comments I regret having answered this question.

Comment: Concerning documentation, it must be clear that it cannot handle each and every case that might pop up. The tutorial itself is clear enough on the transform chain and all possible transforms are listed on the [transforms](https://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html) API page.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sorry that you feel that way.  I was just pushing back on the ever annoying trend on SO of commenters immediately impinging the validity of the OP's question. I dumbed down my question from my actual problem in order to avoid exactly that situation.

Comment: Reducing complexity is indeed desireable. The example you gave in the question is thus well suited. But I think we can all agree that the problem description is indeed insufficient. This is what has been commented on. Plus, ranting about the clearness of the documentation while not providing a clear description oneself will surely not motivate others to provide an answer. If you want further clarification on this, you may look through meta or ask a question there.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm well aware what an Affine transformation is. My comment was intended to help you define your problem better, so you could get the help you needed. It's much easier to help someone if they tell you the things they have tried. I'm sorry you interpreted it as anything other than an attempt to help you, and felt the need to attack those spending their time in an effort to solve your issues.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest and tom, thank you both for your help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by scale you mean multiplication by a factor, you can easily do this via numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot([-3,3],[-3,3])

x = [-1,0,1,1,0,-1]
y = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
scale = 2
poly = Polygon( np.c_[x,y]*scale, facecolor='red', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

The same can be achieved with a `matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D()` transform.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot([-3,3],[-3,3])

x = [-1,0,1,1,0,-1]
y = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]

trans = transforms.Affine2D().scale(2) + ax.transData

poly = Polygon( np.c_[x,y], facecolor='red', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.5, 
               transform=trans)
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

Although it seems a bit overkill for a simple scaling like this.

Comment: Thanks for example on how to properly apply the Affine2D transformation.  The polygon that I'm trying to transform is actually a much more complicated shape and also not in cartesian coordinates, so a simple a matrix multiplication of its coordinates would not work in my case.  The Affine2D() routine did the trick though.